# My VIEWS or WIDGETS from XML is not working at java on a class that extends a fragment class

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

I encountered a problem on my JAVA that extends a fragment class. The CollegeBulletinFragment class, will be loaded on the MainActivity as a Fragment. I know that there is something wrong on the onCreateView method on the CollegeBulletinFragment class especially on the part of button and textview casting, this error outputs a corrupted application (which forcibly close itself) What is the best way to fix it? (see my code for reference)

(Fragment has been imported, ignore the code above the class)

```
public class CollegeBulletinFragment extends Fragment {
    TextView tv;
    Button ccs;
    Button coe;
    public CollegeBulletinFragment(){   
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_collegebulletin, container, false);

        tv = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.tagSample);
        ccs = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.ccs);
        coe = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.coe);

        return rootView;
    }
```

While the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/thesis" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/button6" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="19dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:text="COLLEGE BULLETIN"
        android:textSize="25dp" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/gn"
                android:layout_width="320dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:tag="1"
                android:text="General News" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/ccs"
                android:layout_width="320dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:tag="2"
                android:text="College of Computer Studies" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/coe"
                android:layout_width="320dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:tag="3"
                android:text="College of Engineering" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/coed"
                android:layout_width="320dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:tag="4"
                android:text="College of Education" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/con"
                android:layout_width="320dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:tag="5"
                android:text="College of Nursing" />


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/cba"
                android:layout_width="320dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:tag="6"
                android:text="College of Business and Accountancy" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/cas"
                android:layout_width="320dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:tag="7"
                android:text="College of Arts and Sciences" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/cihm"
                android:layout_width="320dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:tag="8"
                android:text="College of Internation and Hospitality Management" />
        </LinearLayout>



    </ScrollView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tagSample"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtLabel"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtLabel"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fragment's view attribute is set once the onCreateView method returns a result. So instead of using getView() you should use rootView to find it is attributes.

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_collegebulletin, null, false);

        tv = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tagSample);
        ccs = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.ccs);
        coe = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.coe);

        return rootView;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. no need for constructor in this fragment class according
   to me
2. Use rootview instead of getview() that will solve your issue